# Proving a left identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

I have the following question:
[image]

I know that I need to prove that any element with *a+b=1* multiplied by *S* will yield *S*. Can anyone give me a starting point for this proof?

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to multiply matrices? You should search for that then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element with $a+b=1$ is a matrix $$\begin {bmatrix} x & 1-x\\x & 1-x\end {bmatrix} $$

Upon left multiplication by $$\begin {bmatrix} a & b\\a & b\end {bmatrix} $$ we get $$\begin {bmatrix} x & 1-x\\x & 1-x\end {bmatrix} \begin {bmatrix} a & b\\a & b\end {bmatrix} =\begin {bmatrix} a & b\\a & b\end {bmatrix}$$

Thus the statement is valid.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Multiply $\pmatrix {x&1-x\\ x&1-x}$ with  $\pmatrix {a&b\\ a&b}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\a&b\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix} c&d\\c&d\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} c&d\\c&d\end{bmatrix}
$$
for any $c$, $d$, because $a+b=1$. Can you check this?